# intersect dataframes python, keep one dataframe columns

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, inner-join

I would like to join 2 dataframes, so that the result will be the intersection on the two datasets on the key column.
By doing this:

```
result = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='key', how='inner')
```

I will get what I need, but with extra columns of df2. I only want df1 columns in the results. (I do not want to delete them later).

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Well, then you don't want to merge them. Why not simply `df1 = df1[df1["key"].isin(set(df2["key"]))]`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution which will work for one and for multiple keys (joining) columns:

**Setup:**

```
In [28]: a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[10,20,30,40], 'c':list('abcd')})

In [29]: b = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,4,5,6], 'b':[30,41,51,61], 'c':list('efgh')})

In [30]: a
Out[30]:
   a   b  c
0  1  10  a
1  2  20  b
2  3  30  c
3  4  40  d

In [31]: b
Out[31]:
   a   b  c
0  3  30  e
1  4  41  f
2  5  51  g
3  6  61  h
```

multiple joining keys:

```
In [32]: join_cols = ['a','b']

In [33]: a.merge(b[join_cols], on=join_cols)
Out[33]:
   a   b  c
0  3  30  c
```

single joining key:

```
In [34]: join_cols = ['a']

In [35]: a.merge(b[join_cols], on=join_cols)
Out[35]:
   a   b  c
0  3  30  c
1  4  40  d
```

Comment: I didn't mean multiple columns join, rather then something equivalent to: select a.* from a,b where a.key=b.key.  I just want to select the columns of a and not b